# How Can I Implement Search Function with RoomDatabase

Tags: android, kotlin, search, mvvm

I have a issue with implementing search function with RoomDatabase .

I recently implemented search function with retrofit and it was good and no trouble .

But , in without internet condition if the user wants search between products give an error that it's related to the not connection to internet .

So , I decide to implement search function with room and try a lot of code but not get to a proper result . when fill edit text and click on button to get the prdouct by title not result back .

Here some of code I tried :

room table entity :

```
@entity(tableName = cart )
class RoomTables { 

 @primarykey 
 val id : Int ,
 val title : String 
}
```

Dao :

```
  @dao

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cart")
    fun get(): List<RoomTables>
```

Repository :

```
   fun getProduct(title : String): List<RoomTables> = db.GetDao().get().filter { 

    it.title.contains(title , true)}
```

ViewModel :

```
   fun getProduct(title: String) {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {


            repository.getProduct(title)

        }


    }
```

```
HomeACtivity : 

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val viewModel: ViewModelRoom by lazy {

        ViewModelProvider(this, FactoryRoom(RepositoryCart(DataBaseRoom.invoke(this))))
            .get(ViewModelRoom::class.java)
    }


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity)

        val searchBtn: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.btn_search_main)
        val EditTextSearch: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittextSearch)

        val animation: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.simple_anim)
        searchBtn.setOnClickListener {

            btn_search_main.startAnimation(animation)


            viewModel.getProduct(EditTextSearch.text.toString()) }


        EditTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

                viewModel.getProduct(EditTextSearch.text.toString())
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }
        })
```

I also have a recyclerview for display the product in case you want know .

So , any one has any idea that what's the problem ?

I do a lot of search but can't found any resolve .

I hope you guys could hele me with this .

thank's in advanced.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get empty result or error? Also, You can write a query like this: `@Query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE title LIKE :filter")
fun get(filter: String): List<RoomTables>`

Comment: when fill edit text and click on button to get the prdouct by title not result back . I also tried that code you mention

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a result because you're starting a Coroutine with `viewModelScope.launch`. If you want to get a result immediately using coroutines instead of observe and react, then make these changes:

First you should know:

> Room 2.1 adds support for Kotlin coroutines. DAO methods can now be
> marked as suspending to ensure that they are not executed on the main
> thread.

As Florina Muntenescu states [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5).

Your DAO `get` method should look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cart")
suspend fun get(): List<RoomTables>
```

Your Repository `getProduct` method should look like this:

```
suspend fun getProduct(title : String): List<RoomTables> = db.GetDao().get().filter {
    it.title.contains(title , true)
}
```

Your ViewModel `getProduct` method should look like this:

```
suspend fun getProduct(title: String) = repository.getProduct(title)
```

Now in order to call your ViewModel `getProduct` method you should start a coroutine inside your activity like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val productList = viewModel.getProduct(EditTextSearch.text.toString())
    //Do whatever you need with the result here
}
```

To use `lifecycleScope` you need to add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01` or higher to your project.

Also as @iknow suggested you in the comments, you can optimize your query instead of filtering the result on your Repository.

Comment: I implemented your code step by step . but nothing get back . and also no error . there is a way that i get what's the problem is ?

Comment: @BahadorEslami what do you mean by nothing get back? You didn't get a response or you got an empty result?

Comment: I just want when the edit text input is filled and button is clicked the product that is filter get back to me by title . but nothing happened . it's look like something is wrong with my code but I don't know where

Comment: @BahadorEslami Print the result to the console right after the line that calls `viewModel.getProduct` inside the `lifecycleScope.launch` block. You should see the result there. If you're trying to use the result after that block it will seem like it returned nothing and that's because the coroutine that makes the call is doing it concurrently.

Comment: AndroidStudioProjects.grocerystore I/System.out: [] . give me this

Comment: @BahadorEslami Apparently it's returning an empty list. There's something wrong with the query. Make sure the table in your database is not empty and your filter is working. Try removing the filter just to see if the query is returning something,if not then the table is probably empty.